# JSP request.contextPath

Tags: jsp, glassfish-4

Software version:

Glassfish 4.1.x

---

In a JSP, when trying to access the context path, the following code works (for me):

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}`

However, when shorten to:

`${request.contextPath}`

then, either it does not evaluate and therefore evaluated to empty string; or it did work, and simply evaluated to an empty string.

Should not the `request` object be available, as specified by implicit objects in a JSP?  If that it is available, then accessing the context path should work with the shortened version.

Please explain this discrepancy.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043: there is no such `request` implicit object. You seem to be confusing objects available to scriptlets, and objects available to the JSP EL.

Comment: Yes thanks for clearing that up.  Understood now.  Though it is odd that scriptlet objects availability differs to JSP EL (I'm assuming that's the case here).